# pin TabLayout to top and below the toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want to pin TabLayout when scroll

I have tried ...code. but not able to pin TabLayout below toolbar
In this i have toolbar and below that i have cover photo and profile photo etc. below that i have tablayout and viewpager. I'm displaying fragments which is have recyclerview in viewpager.

I want to pin TabLayout which is above the ViewPager (at the bottom). When I scroll down the tabLayout is pinned and the view pager shown(looks something Like tabLayout is pinned below the toolbar).

Here is the example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md13C.jpg

Example Video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=146UaY89cgxQ3XJyZb1Uos-JQjurDL2hW

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".view.ProfileFragment">



    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:title="@string/profile" />


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/coverPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/myToolbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="29dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/coverPhoto"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_person" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/iconChange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light_orange"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/profile_photo"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_round_camera"
            app:tint="@color/white" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@null"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/profile_photo"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` try to add this line in tablayout

Comment: @UsamaAltaf thanks but nothing changed.

Comment: I would be very grateful if anyone can help